# Why I can't change html format to php format

Tags: php

I got admin panel template from Creative TIM and I want to programing it from scratch but I can't write PHP commands inside HTML so I tried change it from dashboard.component.html to dashboard.component.php but I got this result when run website

The Result

[image]

Simple code for test

[image]

Comment: Your service provider likely doesn't support PHP. PHP code has to be passed from apache/nginx to a php executable to be run. If they aren't running php/php-fpm on the server or apache/nginx isn't configured to pass PHP files to php/php-fpm, then it will treat them as plain HTML files.

Comment: @NicholasSummers Do you can leave example below , thanks

Comment: Are you running apache or nginx?

Comment: Please don't post code as image. It really is not difficult to type those three lines as text... (indented with 4 extra spaces).

Comment: @NicholasSummers I guess no , I'm android devloper so I don't have good experience in web languages

Comment: @joel50 I am sorry, but I don't think you (yet) understand enough about PHP or Web Servers to fully understand what needs to be done for us help you with this issue. My recommendation is that you uninstall whatever you have installed and go with a pre-packed solution to web servers such as [XAMMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). That will at least get you to a point where you can test your PHP code. Getting familiar with nginx or apache can be done later.

Comment: Read [Install and Configure PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php)

Comment: This is Angular, you can't run PHP code inside a NodeJS server and worst, inside an Angular application. Is like trying to install an Android app in iOS is not going to happen. You need to take the PHP part and put it anywhere else and then, configure a XAMPP/WAMPP/LAMPP or something like that (if you don't know how to install Nginx and PHP from scratch for example) and put it there. So PHP is going to be your backend, and you create this frontend SPA to connect to your backend using HTTP Request.